# Compress folder on grunt is not working

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-compress

I am trying to compress a folder on grunting. I used the following code in Gruntfile.js

```
    compress: {
      main : {
        options : {
          archive : "myapp.zip"
        },
        files : [
          { expand: true, src : "src/partials/templates", cwd : "target/dev/" }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Folder structure

```
--mainfolder
----src
------partials
----target
------dev
----gruntfile.js
```

But it is not working. I am new to this. Did i miss anything? Why it is not working?

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: What does your folder structure look like?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If you run your grunt command with `--verbose` it might give you more information about why it's failing.

Comment: am not getting any errors. I tried using --verbose. The thing is here it is not even getting triggered i guess. Because anything related to compress is not visible in command prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just run your conf with your folder strcture and it worked for me, I have a myapp.zip in your ./mainfolder

Are you up do date with your nodeJS version (0.10 or 0.12) grunt and compress (my compress is 0.9.1 currently)?

Could you copy the output of your console?

Comment: It was a silly mistake actually. I didn't add compress in grunt.registerTask. Thanks alot.